# Using Forms Auth. with Claims Based Auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims-based-identity, adfs

Using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh987037%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) guide I've implemented claims based auth on ASP.NET Webforms successfully. But the problem is while using claims based auth. you cannot use forms based auth in the same app pool:

```
  <authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>

  <authentication mode="None" />
```

Is there a way to use both?

Comment: Not true, you can have both modules, the session authentication and forms authentication in thr same app. The authorization section is the same in both. Most probably what you ask about is not the real issue.

Comment: so how can I do that?

Comment: Can do what? You have to rephrase your question somehow to make it more specific.